# Preserve remote IP (to secure endpoints) when using apache ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse

Tags: java, apache, jboss

We currently have an apache server passing requests to a JBoss server where our application is running.  On the JBoss side, in the ContainerRequestFilter implementation I'm getting a handle on the HttpServletRequest object in order to get the remote address (request.getRemoteAddr()). However, the IP returned is the IP of the Apache server, not the remote host.

I'm aware I can look at the request header, "x-forwarded-for" to find the "real" IP address, however the IP address is being used to restrict access to certain rest endpoints in our application.  Anyone see the problem here?  A quick spoof of the x-forwarded-for header and I'm in.

My question is: how can I preserve the remote IP address to restrict access to our endpoints and not use the "x-forwarded-for" header at all since it's just waiting to be abused?

Here's our abbreviated apache config file:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.42.60:80>
  ....
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
  RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.ourappaddress.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
  ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.42.60:443>
  ProxyPass / http://appserver:8080/app
  ProxyPassReverse / http://appserver:8080/app
</VirtualHost>
```

And here is the simplififed interceptor code:

```
package com.ourcompany.interceptor;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import com.ourcompany.interceptor.annotation.IpRestricted;


@Provider @IpRestricted
public class IpInspector implements ContainerRequestFilter {
  @Context
  HttpServletRequest request;

  @Override
  public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext)
      throws IOException {

    String ip = request.getRemoteAddr(); // this gives me apache's IP, not remote IP!

    if (!isIpAuthorized(ip)) {
      containerRequestContext.abortWith(Response.ok("not authorized").build());
    }
  }
```